# Using WINE on Catalina / opening Freehand files

Tags: mac, catalina, error, wine

I have a Mac updated to Catalina, on which I've installed Wine 1.8.6. I use Wine just to launch the legacy app Freehand (in a Windows version), to convert some old graphic files.

However, I am surprised that many versions of Wine don't install on Catalina. v1.8.6 was the only one that I was able to install; and when I go to launch an .exe file,, Wine gives me an error:

> Prefix creation exited with error - You find a logfile to help with
> debugging on your desktop.

I don't know how to fix this problem. Anybody know a good and straightforward solution?

Comment: Wine non funziona su Catalina, perch'è '32-bit', e vietato. Torna indietro a Mojave (sul disco esterno); o magari prova un altro modo di convertire i file di Freehand. (E fa tutti loro!)

Answer (score 2):

Wine doesn't work on Catalina, because it uses 32-bit code, which is no longer allowed on MacOS.

There are other ways you can open old Freehand files. FH10 files can be opened in Preview and Affinity Designer. Alternatively, install Mojave on an external disk and boot to that; or run Mojave in a VM. Or find a friend with a Windows PC.

You could try CrossOver, which is another Windows emulator that works on Catalina. It is paid-for software, but there's a 14-day trial, which should be long enough to convert all your files. https://www.codeweavers.com/crossover

Comment: Crossover is built on Wine - Many wine developers are employed by codewavers who sell crossover - and the winehq site is hosted by codeweavers - so it is not exactly another emulator but as winhq says "CrossOver is a polished version of Wine provided by CodeWeavers"

Comment: @mmmmmm Yes, but from what I can gather, the implementation used by CrossOver to get 32-bit apps working has been ruled out for WINE itself.